# Browser sets a cookie value without JS nor Set-Cookie

Tags: http, cookies

If you look at the post request below, for some reason, on a given website, my browser sets a cookie value "s_vi=2A" that is not in any previous **Set-Cookie** header responses nor using javascript (javascript is disabled in the browser). All the other values (JID, BID, etc.) come from previous 'Set-Cookie' header responses.

How is that possible? Where does this value might come from?

```
POST /auth.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: ea.com:443
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: JID=0C; BID=7d; WID=ea; sitecontext=5b; s_vi=2A
Origin: https://ea.com
Referer: https://ea.com/w
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
```

Comment: is it an old value? have you cleared cookies and seen it re-set?

Comment: I cleared my cookies for this domain and traced the whole request to track requests/responses

Comment: do you have a toolbar installed on your browser that could be doing that?

Comment: Good point. Let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be coming from a previous set-cookie header response...  You just need to look more for it.  It might be coming from an image request... those can contain set-cookie header responses too.  I suggest you clear your cookies and re-test.  In addition to watching the network request-responses in the debugging view of your browser, you should open the cookies view and keep an eye on the cookies as they're created.

Comment: You were right. I missed a request that added this value. Now I am sure that there's no other way beside previous request or JS. Thank you Joseph.